# Create IConnectableObservable<string> from process - output buffer issue

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Below is my attempt to turn a System.Diagnostics.Process into an IConnectableObservable.
This solution has a problem: I'd like to listen to the standard output and error continiously and use the event Process.Exited as trigger for OnCompleted. Unfortunately I found out that Process.Exited is raised **before** output buffers are empty. This means that without my ugly workaround with a thread sleep I can reproduce situations where the output is not served via OnNext statements.

Q1: Do you see any workaround for this issue?

Q2: With regard to System.Reactive: What could I have done better in my solution?

regards,

Markus

```
public static class RxProcessUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a connectable observable for a process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Must be a connectable observable in order to hinder multiple 
    /// subscriptions to call the process multiple times.</remarks>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IConnectableObservable<string> CreateConnectableObservableProcess
        (string filename, string arguments, IObservable<string> input = null)
    {
        var observable = Observable.Using(() =>
            {
                Process process = new Process();

                // process configuration
                process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                if (null != input)
                {
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

                    input.Subscribe(s =>
                        {
                            if (!process.HasExited)
                            {
                                process.StandardInput.Write(s);
                            }
                        });
                }

                return process;
            },
            process =>
            {
                return Observable.Create<string>(
                (IObserver<string> observer) =>
                {
                    // listen to stdout and stderr
                    var stdOut = RxProcessUtilities.CreateStandardOutputObservable(process);
                    var stdErr = RxProcessUtilities.CreateStandardErrorObservable(process);

                    var stdOutSubscription = stdOut.Subscribe(observer);
                    var stdErrSubscription = stdErr.Subscribe(observer);

                    var processExited = Observable.FromEventPattern
                    (h => process.Exited += h, h => process.Exited -= h);

                    var processError = processExited.Subscribe(args =>
                    {
                        // Here is my problem: process sends exited event *before* all 
                        // *DataReceived events have been raised

                        // My ugly workaround for process exit before stdout and stderr buffers are empty.
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);

                        // Also: AFAICS we cannot read synchronously what is left in the buffer, 
                        // since we started asynchronously. This will throw:
                        // string restOfStdOut = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        // string restOfStdErr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                        {
                            observer.OnError(new Exception
                                (String.Format("Process '{0}' terminated with error code {1}",
                                 process.StartInfo.FileName, process.ExitCode)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            observer.OnCompleted();
                        }
                    });

                    process.Start();

                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    return new CompositeDisposable
                        (stdOutSubscription,
                         stdErrSubscription,
                         processError);
                });
            });

        return observable.Publish();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an IObservable&lt;string&gt; for the standard error of a process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IObservable<string> CreateStandardErrorObservable(Process process)
    {
        // var processExited = Observable.FromEventPattern
        //    (h => process.Exited += h, h => process.Exited -= h);

        var receivedStdErr =
            Observable.FromEventPattern<DataReceivedEventHandler, DataReceivedEventArgs>
                (h => process.ErrorDataReceived += h,
                 h => process.ErrorDataReceived -= h)
            //.TakeUntil(processExited) 
            // cannot be used here, since process exited event might be raised 
            // before all stderr and stdout events occurred.
            .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Data);

        return Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
        {
            var cancel = Disposable.Create(process.CancelErrorRead);

            return new CompositeDisposable(cancel, receivedStdErr.Subscribe(observer));
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an IObservable&lt;string&gt; for the standard output of a process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IObservable<string> CreateStandardOutputObservable(Process process)
    {
        var receivedStdOut =
            Observable.FromEventPattern<DataReceivedEventHandler, DataReceivedEventArgs>
            (h => process.OutputDataReceived += h,
             h => process.OutputDataReceived -= h)
            .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Data);

        return Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
        {
            var cancel = Disposable.Create(process.CancelOutputRead);

            return new CompositeDisposable(cancel, receivedStdOut.Subscribe(observer));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Below [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) I found a hint to use WaitForExit() in order to flush stdout: "This overload ensures that all processing has been completed, including the handling of asynchronous events for redirected standard output." and also a hint to use Process.Close(). So this might be an answer to Q1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx: "This overload [WaitForExit()] ensures that all processing has been completed, including the handling of asynchronous events for redirected standard output. You should use this overload after a call to the WaitForExit(Int32) overload when standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers."

Here is the complete solution:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a connectable observable for a process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Must be a connectable observable in order to hinder multiple subscriptions to call the process multiple times.</remarks>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IConnectableObservable<string> CreateConnectableObservableProcess(string filename, string arguments, IObservable<string> input = null)
    {
        var observable = Observable.Using(() =>
            {
                Process process = new Process();

                // process configuration
                process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                if (null != input)
                {
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

                    input.Subscribe(s =>
                        {
                            if (!process.HasExited)
                            {
                                process.StandardInput.Write(s);
                            }
                        });
                }

                return process;
            },
            process =>
            {
                return Observable.Create<string>(
                    (IObserver<string> observer) =>
                    {
                        // listen to stdout and stderr
                        var stdOut = RxProcessUtilities.CreateStandardOutputObservable(process);
                        var stdErr = RxProcessUtilities.CreateStandardErrorObservable(process);

                        var stdOutSubscription = stdOut.Subscribe(observer);
                        var stdErrSubscription = stdErr.Subscribe(observer);

                        var processExited = Observable.FromEventPattern(h => process.Exited += h, h => process.Exited -= h);

                        var processError = processExited.Subscribe(args =>
                        {
                            process.WaitForExit();

                            try
                            {
                                if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                                {
                                    observer.OnError(new Exception(String.Format("Process '{0}' terminated with error code {1}",
                                        process.StartInfo.FileName, process.ExitCode)));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    observer.OnCompleted();
                                }
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                process.Close();
                            }
                        });

                        process.Start();

                        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                        return new CompositeDisposable(stdOutSubscription,
                                                       stdErrSubscription,
                                                       processError);
                    });
            });

        return observable.Publish();
    }
```

Comment: Is it somehow possible to add cancellation to this solution? I want to stopp the process by clicking a button or something.